# logout from coovachilli using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coovachilli

I have created captive portal which working for coovachilli , 
the login page is in cloud  for example

```
app.paychilli.com/login.php
```

so when one user connected to the wifi he will redirect to this address to make login to his account .
the coovachilli is in local for example

```
192.168.2.1
```

so after user login and access his account ,I want to make logout button which will allow him logout ,I want to do it with ajax , without redirect user to logout page .
to logout from coovachilli

```
192.168.2.1/logout
```

when I using ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '192.168.2.1/logout',

            success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#username').val(email);
        $('#password').val(data);//$('#loginbtn').click();

            }
        });
```

I had this domain cross error in console , how can I solve this problem , I need to allow user logout from coovachilli without making any redirect